# Treeshaking * imports with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-material

If we import material modules like this:

```
import * as material from '@angular/material';
let materialModules = [material.MatBadgeModule];
```

Now we would use the `materialModules` array for our shared material module import / export declarations.

If we do it like this will Angular import all material modules with the application, or will it only include the ones that are declared in `NgModule`s import and export declarations?

Comment: Keep in mind that in [Angular Material 8](https://github.com/angular/components/releases/tag/8.0.0) `Importing directly from the root @angular/material entry-point is deprecated.`

Comment: Good to know - Thanks!